# PHP array output just first value

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to write data from MySQL to PHP-Array (to generate a XML file with the PHP library FluidXML ). When I echo the array, I only get the first value of it, but when I echo a variable with the same data as the array I get correct output with all the information. Let me explain more exactly:

The query to get data:

```
$sql = sprintf("select b.nPosID, b.nAmount, b.sName, ......."); 
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Then I loop trough the results:

```
$msg = "";
$orderArticles = [];
$orderSubArticles = [];

while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
     if($data['sChange'] != null) {
        $msg .= ' * ' . $data['sChange'] . '  ' . number_format($data['nAmount'] * $data['nPriceChange'], 2) . "\r\n"; 
        $orderSubArticles[] = ['SubArticle' => [
             'ArticleNo' => '0',
             'ArticleName' => $data['sChange'],
             'Count' => $data['nAmount'],
             'Price' => $data['nPriceChange']
             ],];
    }

    if ($nPosID != $data['nPosID']) { 
        $msg .= " \r\n" . $data['nAmount'] . ' x ' .  $data['sName'] . '  ' . number_format($data['nAmount'] * $data['nPrice'], 2) . "\r\n"; 
        $orderArticles[] = ['Article' => [
             'ArticleNo' => '0',
             'ArticleName' => $data['sName'],
             'ArticleSize' => '0',
             'Count' => $data['nAmount'],
             'Price' => $data['nPrice'],
             'Tax' => '10',
                    'SubArticleList' => [
                            $orderSubArticles
             ]],];
     }
}
```

Let's assume, from the SQL query I get the following correct output:

```
Pizza
   + extra cheese
   + extra tonno
```

When I echo $msg variable, I get the same correct result. But when I echo the array, I only get the first value:

```
Pizza
   + extra cheese
```

To be exactly, the output which was generated with the values from the array:

```
<ArticleList>
  <Article>
    <ArticleName>Pizza</ArticleName>
    <Count>1</Count>
    <Price>12.9</Price>
    <SubArticleList>
       <SubArticle>
          <ArticleName>Extra cheese</ArticleName>
          <Count>1</Count>
          <Price>3</Price>
       </SubArticle>
    </SubArticleList>
  </Article>
</ArticleList>
```

So the second `<SubArticle>` is missing (extra tonno).

Comment: Can you add the  output of `var_dump($result)`?

Comment: I'm getting "resource(19) of type (mysql result)".

Answer (score -1):

Without knowing how your resultset really looks like, I am doubting your assumption is correct, that a result/row in the set really contains both subarticles. That would lastly mean all results have two subarticles and that's supposingly not the case, because then it would need to return something like sChange1, sChange2 ...

Even if the results would look something like that and contain two or more sub articles, your code only assigns one of them to the subArticles-array per result.

Comment: I know what you mean. So what do you think is the correct way to solve this?

Comment: @Emre Beloz It depends on how the resultset really looks like. Please show output of var_dump($results).

Comment: Like I commented above, I get "resource(19) of type (mysql result)". When you need the content of the array, then I have to replace $results with $orderArticles and $orderSubArticles. Danke dir..